# How to parse `chunked` response by split symbol?

Tags: javascript, chunked-encoding

I have a backend api with chunked response. Each chunk - json array of objects which ends with new line `\n`.

In browser, I make request on button click:

```
searchBtn.onclick = function () {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", "/api/p2p_search" + text, true);
            xhr.onprogress = function () {
                var searchArray = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                //show array in result
            };
            xhr.send();
        };
```

But sometimes instead one valid json array chunk i receive multiple chunks, so I cant parse it. For example:`[{"hello":` and `"world"}]`.

Is't there a way to really receive chunks splitted by line or another way to receive chunked response?

Comment: Have you tried massaging `responseText`? e.g. concatenating multiple chunks or removing invalid `\n`'s?

Comment: Are you trying to emulate an [event stream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource)? Do you need the individual chunks asynchronously, access them while still streaming, or is it fine to read only when the whole response is received?

Comment: Yes, I need show individual chunk in browser as I receive it. Something like dynamic list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution with https://github.com/eBay/jsonpipe which "buffers" data to valid json. Delimeter configurable, in my case `\n`:

```
  <script src="jsonpipe.js"></script>

  var jsonpipe = require('jsonpipe');
    /**
     * @param {String} url A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
     * @param {Object} url A set of key/value pairs that configure the Ajax request.
     * @return {XMLHttpRequest} The XMLHttpRequest object for this request.
     * @method flow
     */
    jsonpipe.flow('http://api.com/items?q=batman', {
        "delimiter": "\n", // String. The delimiter separating valid JSON objects; default is "\n\n"
        "onHeaders": function(statusText, headers) {
            // Do something with the headers and the statusText.
        }
        "success": function(data) {
            // Do something with this JSON chunk
        },
        "error": function(errorMsg) {
            // Something wrong happened, check the error message
        },
        "complete": function(statusText) {
            // Called after success/error, with the XHR status text
        },
        "timeout": 3000, // Number. Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request
        "method": "GET", // String. The type of request to make (e.g. "POST", "GET", "PUT"); default is "GET"
        "headers": { // Object. An object of additional header key/value pairs to send along with request
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
        },
        "data": "", // String. A serialized string to be sent in a POST/PUT request,
        "withCredentials": true // Boolean. Send cookies when making cross-origin requests; default is true
    });
```